# How does stopwords.words('english') work here?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nltk, stop-words

I have used two different data sets to train as I mentioned on both examples

```
x_train = ['This !was awesome movie',
           'It is Wonderful movie',
           'Yeah it is bad movie @',
           'bad movie not upto the mark',
           'Good movie good acting?']
```

I have imported the libraries

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
import re
```

Example 1:

```
def change(data):
    clean_1=data.lower()
    clean_2= re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '',clean_1)  
    clean_3= [word_tokenize(clean_2) ]
    clean_4= [j for i in clean_3 for j in i if j not in stopwords.words('english')]

    return clean_3
```

Getting 3d list result while returning clear_3.So for that i have use 2 for loops on clear_4 and compare a 1d list with stopwords:

```
[[['this', 'was', 'awesome', 'movie']],
[['it', 'is', 'wonderful', 'movie']],
[['yeah', 'it', 'is', 'bad', 'movie']],
[['bad', 'movie', 'not', 'upto', 'the', 'mark']],
[['good', 'movie', 'good', 'acting']]]
```

Example 2:

```
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
text=fetch_20newsgroups()

def change(data):
    clean_4=[]
    clean_1=data.lower()
    clean_2=[re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',clean_1) ]    
    clean_3= [word_tokenize(i) for i in clean_2]
    clean_4= [i for i in clean_3 if i not in stopwords.words('english')]
    return clean_3
```

getting 3d List on clean_3 but i have used one for loop here and i got the result. Can someone please tell me why it is happening?

```
[[['from',
'lerxstwamumdedu',
'wheres',
'my',
'thing',
'subject',
'this']]]
```

On first example when i was using one for loop i was getting an error while not getting on second example when I used one for loop

Comment: I can't understand your question. What is your desired output for this sentence `'It is Wonderful movie'`? is it simply `['It', 'Wonderful', 'movie']`?

Comment: My question is on eg 1 I used 2 for loops for getting result while on example 2 I have used one for loop on stopwords. Words('english')

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to break this down a bit, by including the `type`s of each of the variables.

```py
def change(data: str): # data: str
    clean_1=data.lower() # clean_1: str
    clean_2= re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '',clean_1) # clean_2: str
    clean_3= [word_tokenize(clean_2) ] # clean_3: List[List[str]]
    # This is where you might get confused! word_tokenize() will already return a List,
    # and you wrap that in *another* list. So, clean_3: List[List[str]]
    # The outer list always has a length of 1.
    clean_4= [j for i in clean_3 for j in i if j not in stopwords.words('english')]
    # clean_4: List[str]
    # Here, you "fold" these two nested lists into one list.
    # For example, if clean_3 = [['this', 'was', 'awesome', 'movie']]
    # then clean_4 = ['awesome', 'movie']

    return clean_3 # Return a List[List[str]]

# Note that you use something like:
print([change(sent) for sent in x_train])
# So, this wraps the output of change(sent) in another list!
# this means that we print List[List[List[str]]]
```

Let's try the same for the second example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_20newsgroups
text=fetch_20newsgroups()

def change(data: str): # data: str
    clean_4=[] # clean_4: List
    clean_1=data.lower() # clean_1: str
    clean_2=[re.sub(r'[^\w\s]','',clean_1) ] # clean_2: List[str]
    # Note! This is where you wrap the string in a big list.
    # If the input to `change` was `"From: lerxst@wam.umd.edu (where's my thing)"`,
    # then clean_2 will be ['from lerxstwamumdedu wheres my thing'].
    # This is different from the first example.
    # This list always just has a length of 1
    clean_3= [word_tokenize(i) for i in clean_2] # clean_3: List[List[str]]
    # Here, ['from lerxstwamumdedu wheres my thing'] becomes
    # [['from', 'lerxstwamumdedu', 'wheres', 'my', 'thing']]
    clean_4= [i for i in clean_3 if i not in stopwords.words('english')]
    # clean_4: List[List[str]]
    # This is where your question comes in: Why 1 loop here, instead of 2?
    # Well, because the 1 loop doesn't work. If `clean_3` is
    # [['from', 'lerxstwamumdedu', 'wheres', 'my', 'thing']],
    # then clean_4 will also be [['from', 'lerxstwamumdedu', 'wheres', 'my', 'thing']]

    # The loop checks `for i in clean_3`, so `i` can be
    # `['from', 'lerxstwamumdedu', 'wheres', 'my', 'thing']`,
    # and then it checks if `i not in stopwords`.
    # However, this list `['from', 'lerxstwamumdedu', 'wheres', 'my', 'thing']`
    # is definitely never going to occur inside of `stopwords`,
    # so the output of clean_4 is just [['from', 'lerxstwamumdedu', 'wheres', 'my', 'thing']]

    # If you used [j for i in clean_3 for j in i if j not in stopwords.words('english')]
    # like in example 1, then the output is:
    # ['lerxstwamumdedu', 'wheres', 'thing']
    return clean_3
```

I hope that clarified the difference between your two examples somewhat. To help you out further, I'll provide a snippet of how I would do this:

```py
from typing import List
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

def change_3(data: str) -> List[str]:
    clean_1 = data.lower()
    clean_2 = re.sub(r'[^\w\s]', '', clean_1)
    clean_3 = word_tokenize(clean_2)
    exclude = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    clean_4 = [word for word in clean_3 if word not in exclude]
    return clean_4 # Or clean_3, if you don't want to exclude stopwords
```

If you want, you can determine the `type` of each of the variables in my `change_3` yourself, to see if you understand it.

Comment: Thanks you very much. One doubt-> so we have to give a 1d list to word_tokenize() and stopwords and Porterstemmer.stem()?

Comment: No need! [`word_tokenize`](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html?highlight=word_tokenize#nltk.tokenize.word_tokenize) takes a string as input, and so does PorterStemmer.stem(). No lists needed there. For stopwords you can use a for-loop (or list comprehension) over a list of words to check whether a (string) word is in the stopwords.

Comment: Hi Tom I am using ->clean_4= [j for i in clean_3 for j in i if j not in stopwords.words('english')]  as you mentioned on example -2 but now my jupyter notebok going on infinite loop and i am not getting any result

Comment: That is a bit strange. I don't know why that is happening